# loading alternate tables in alternate workflow executions in Informatica

Tags: informatica

I want to load Target1 in first run of workflow and load Target2 in second run of same workflow and Target1 in third run of same workflow and so on...Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Workflow with a persistent variable (eg. $$runCnt) with default value as 1. Use AssignmentTask to flip the variable value `IIF($$runCnt=1, 2, 1)`. Link the AssignmentTask with two sessions, eg. s_Target1 and s_Target2. Use following conditions on the links:

- AssignmentTask to s_Target1 link condition: $$runCnt=1
- AssignmentTask to s_Target2 link condition: $$runCnt=2

The two Sessions should reuse same mapping, just override 'Target Table Name' property to use the appropriate table in each one of them.